# Is there anyway to shorten VB.net code?

Tags: vb.net

Here my VB codes, can I shorten into one or two line ?

```
cmbnA.Text = 1
cmbnJ.Text = 1
cmbnC.Text = 1
cmbsA.Text = "Standard"
cmbsJ.Text = "Standard"
cmbsC.Text = "Standard"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a colon to end a line.

```
cmbnA.Text = 1 : cmbnJ.Text = 1 'etc...
```

The question is why would you want to?  It's not like it makes a difference when the program runs, and it makes the functionality more obfuscated.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this syntax:

```
Array.ForEach(Of TextBox)({cmbnA, cmbnJ, cmbnC}, Sub(a) a.Text = "1")
```

Although I would seriously look into making this code more maintainable, not shorter.

Start with giving your TextBoxes better names.

Answer (score 0):

Ummh, I don't think it's possible. You could try using a `with` statement but that'll
only reduce the number of characters, not lines. Matter of fact the lines will increase.

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible. You may reduce it to one/two lines using colon, but that is just for readability. It has no other impact what so ever.